# How to use FreeTTS in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, import, freetts

I need to use FreeTTS in a Java program. It's a really small application that just speaks out a certain text that was typed in by the user. I have no idea how to get this work though... I have downloaded the .zip from the FreeTTS site ( http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php ), but how should I proceed to get it to work?  As IDE I use IntelliJ IDEA. Could someone help me get to how to use it? I've never really manually added something to use in applications, I wonder, when it's added, how it can be used in a program (via import?). I hope someone can help me here, thanks in advance.

Extra info: I'm using a Mac.